# How to get results from Sonatype Nexus REST API in JSON format

Tags: json, api, rest, nexus

I'm using Sonatype Nexus REST core api to get repositories.

The output format is XML. How can I get the output in JSON format?

I can see in the docs that the return type can be `application/json`. But I am completely in blank where to set this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As an example with curl here is a call to get the list of repositories

```
curl http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories
```

which will give you xml formatted output. To get the same in JSON format you just edit the HTTP header of the request like so

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories
```

Potentially you want to add credentials and specify the content type as well (especially if you are posting JSON load as part of the request). You can also change to a POST..

```
curl -X GET -u admin:admin123 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories
```

Comment: how to give authorization in url for nexus repository?